# Finite State Machine HW/SW event trigger

Tags: c, state-machine, fsm

I'm trying to write a code in C for the FSM of a Vending Machine.
I'm assuming that the machine has 3 basic buttons -- Insert Coins, Choose Product, OK.

I'm going by the concept of creating a look up table with current state, event trigger, next state. I also have an array of function pointers that executes the corresponding function for each state.
However, I am confused on what needs to be chosen as the event trigger.

This is what I have now:

```
typedef void (*fsmFuncPtr_t)(void);

fsmFuncPtr_t fsmFuncPtr[] =
{
    &Idle_State_Handler,
    &Insert_Coins_Handler,
    &Choose_Product_Handler,
    &Validate_Product_Handler,
    &Validate_Coins_Handler,
    &Dispense_Product_Handler,
    &Return_Change_Handler
}

typedef struct
{
    fsmState_e cState;
    fsmInput_e input;
    fsmState_e nState;  
} fsm_t;

fsmState_e currentState = IDLE_STATE;
fsmEvent_e currentEvent = No_Input;

fsm_t fsm[] =
{
   // cState                event                     nState
   {IDLE_STATE,             No_Input_Event,           IDLE_STATE},
   {IDLE_STATE,             Insert_Coins_Event,       COIN_INSERTION_STATE},
   {COIN_INSERTION_STATE,   No_Input_Event,           COIN_INSERTION_STATE},
   {COIN_INSERTION_STATE,   Choose_Product_Event,     PRODUCT_CHOOSING_STATE},
   {PRODUCT_CHOOSING_STATE, OK_Product,               VALIDATE_PRODUCT_STATE},
   {VALIDATE_PRODUCT_STATE, Product_Valid_Event,      VALIDATE_COINS_STATE},
   {VALIDATE_PRODUCT_STATE, Product_Invalid_Event,    VALIDATE_PRODUCT_STATE},
   {VALIDATE_COINS_STATE,   Sufficient_Coins_Event,   DISPENSE_PRODUCT_STATE},
   {VALIDATE_COINS_STATE,   Insufficient_Coins_Event, COIN_INSERTION_STATE},
   {DISPENSE_PRODUCT_STATE, Balance_Available_Event,  RETURN_CHANGE_STATE},
   {DISPENSE_PRODUCT_STATE, Balance_Unavailable_Event,IDLE_STATE},
   {RETURN_CHANGE_STATE,    Change_Returned_Event,    IDLE_STATE},
};

void main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int fsmTableSize = sizeof(fsm)/sizeof(fsm[0]);

        for(i=0; i < fsmTableSize; i++)
        {
            // intend to get HW triggers here?
            if((currentState == fsm[i].cState) && (currentEvent == fsm[i].event) && (fsm[i].fsmFuncPtr != NULL))
            {
                fsm[i].fsmFuncPtr();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here, No_Input_Event, Insert_Coins_Event, Choose_Product_Event and Ok_Product_Event are events that are triggered by HW. However, all the validation events are events that would be triggered by SW/FW based on the current values of product code and available number of coins. So I'm confused where I should be obtaining/manipulating these events.
Or should I only have the HW triggers as triggers and just make silent state transitions based on validation results ?

Comment: Your question is about... What?

Comment: I’m trying to understand an embedded FSM design in C. Could there be both HW and SW event triggers for state transitions ? And what would be the best place to update these events ?

Comment: 'Could there be both HW and SW event triggers' sure:)  'best place to update these events ? ' well, I like to serialize all events/actions, irrespective of source, by queueing event messages to one thread that runs the state machine.  I find other approaches undebuggable:(